# Expected number of heads, stopping at n heads

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

I flip a coin once a second, for $t$ seconds. If I get $n$ heads before time is up, I stop.

What is the expected number of heads, assuming the coin is fair (probability of a head is 0.5).

I believe the answer is $$E[\text{number of heads}] = \min\left(n,\frac{t}{2}\right),$$

but I'm not sure of a formal proof.

Comment: Well, you have to consider the probabilities of each.  For $n=1, t=3$ for instance we see that we get $0$ with probability $\frac 18$ and $1$ with probability $\frac 78$ so the answer is $\frac 78$ which is not $\min \left(1,\frac 32\right)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In effect you have a truncated binomial distribution so the expected number of heads is $$\sum\limits_{i=0}^t {t \choose i}\frac{\min(i,n)}{2^t}= n - \sum\limits_{i=n+1}^t {t \choose i}\frac{i-n}{2^t} = \frac t2 - \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} {t \choose i}\frac{n-i}{2^t}$$  which is smaller than your expression